# hough transform in a rectangular shape

Tags: image, math, image-processing, computer-vision

[image: rectangular shape]

[image: empty shape]

Our aim, find vanishing point of rectangular shape. I want to apply hough transform this shape with y=mx+c. Than, after hough transform, I have to show two or more vote points on (m,c) axis second shape. I dont know how I apply. please help me.

Comment: What is your input?  Do you know the coordinates of the corners?

Comment: Vanishing point is misused in this context.  I believe what you meant is you want to find the point where at least two lines of your shape intersect if you were to find the Hough Transform.  You can clearly see that it would happen at `(x,y) = (2.5,2.5)`.

Comment: I know wanishing point. My problem is hough transform. I have to show (m,c)  points, that  two or more vote after hough transform on rectangular shape, on second picture.

Comment: Good luck with your homework!

Comment: I am working my exam thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of Hough transform is that you basically draw all possible lines and then try to figure out which ones are really present in the image.

So, for your images, try to draw all possible horizontal/vertical lines and count the black points under each. Fot example - take horizontal line with y = 0(1,2,3..). Check the color of all points with x=[0...width] and y=0. If all or most of them are black - you have a line. Repeat with y=[1...height].

After you have the coordinates of all lines, you can find the gaps in each line in the same fashion - check all the points that should belong to the line and note the white ones. When you have enough white points in a row - there is a gap.

This method will help detecting few points of a figure on your first picture. Then you just have to connect them together to get your shape.